# How to do One to One association in hibernate with foreign key and join table and unidirectional

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I wish to have a one to one association with a join table in unidirectional way. -

Tables :

1. A (A_id, D_id, A_Data)
2. B (A_id, C_id) // Join table just contain relation between A and C
3. C (C_id, C_Data)

   ```
   Class A {
      .
      .
   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(name = "B",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_id", referencedColumnName = "A_id"), 
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "C_id", referencedColumnName = "C_id"))
   private C c;
   }
   ```

I am using hibernate with jpa 2.0.
Entity D is not important in the model hence ignored.
I only wish to read data ,hence insert/update/delete use cases should not be concern, but one can suggest best practice in that case also.

This setup does not work. Can some one suggest how to do it in correct way?

It gives following exception

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: A_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(A) and its related supertables and secondary tables
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly doesn't work for you? Any error messages would be helpful.

Comment: Why you need this relationship? If you want one-to-one add an extra field with @OneToOne  in A or C

Comment: The database exist since long and I do not wish to change in schema.

Comment: `@JoinTable(name = "B",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "C_id", referencedColumnName = "id")` while doing reference columnname it should be related to your fields which is present in entity

Comment: It looks not true. The value of _referencedColumnName_ should always be a column name.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your desired schema:

```
    // Given the following C entity
    @Entity
    public class C {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "C_ID")
        private long id;

        private String C_Data;

        //...
    }


    // A Entity should be 
    @Entity
    public class A {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "A_ID")
        private long id;

        private String A_Data;

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
        @JoinTable(name = "B", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "C_id", unique = true))
        private C c;

        //...

    }
```

I've omitted `referencedColumnName`, so hibernate will map it to the entity primary key.

Note also that `A_id` column of `B` table will be the primary key.